# Exporting a lazily initialized bean (which implements SelfNaming and is annotated with ManagedResource annotation) gives IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, jmx, lazy-initialization, spring-jmx

I'm having a bean that is

- annotated with `ManagedResource`
- lazily initialized
- implements `SelfNaming`

I'm exporting it using spring's `AnnotationMBeanExporter`.

All this works good when I'm using spring version `4.3.16.RELEASE`, but when I upgraded my spring version to `5.0.5.RELEASE` or `5.1.3.RELEASE` this code started giving me `IllegalStateException`.

My Bean definition and the spring's context.xml looks like this:

SampleBean.java:

```
package com.jmx.trial.dummybeans;

import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.SelfNaming;

import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

@ManagedResource
public class SampleBean implements SelfNaming {
    @Override
    public ObjectName getObjectName() throws MalformedObjectNameException {
        return new ObjectName("com.jmx.trial:name=sampleBean");
    }
}
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="server" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter">
        <property name="server" ref="server"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sampleBean" class="com.jmx.trial.dummybeans.SampleBean" lazy-init="true"/>

</beans>
```

I understand that an extra validation was added [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/jmx/export/MBeanExporter.java#L1115), and this is causing `IllegalStateException` but I'm not completely sure why that was added.

The stack-trace looks like this:

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [sampleBean] with key 'sampleBean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not initialized

    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:551)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:551)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.jmx.trial.MBeanExporterTest.testBeanExportedWithXml(MBeanExporterTest.java:79)
    at com.jmx.trial.MBeanExporterTest.testForLazyAutoDetectWithSelfNaming(MBeanExporterTest.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not initialized
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter$NotificationPublisherAwareLazyTargetSource.postProcessTargetObject(MBeanExporter.java:1115)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.LazyInitTargetSource.getTarget(LazyInitTargetSource.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter$NotificationPublisherAwareLazyTargetSource.getTarget(MBeanExporter.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicUnadvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:475)
    at com.jmx.trial.dummybeans.SampleBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9cd1c95b.getObjectName(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.getObjectName(MBeanExporter.java:752)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerLazyInit(MBeanExporter.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:596)
    ... 33 more
```

My experiments:

- When I don't lazily initialize the `sampleBean`, I don't get this `IllegalStateException`.
- When I annotate SampleBean with `ManagedResource(objectName = "com.jmx.trial:name=sampleBean")` and make `SampleBean` *not* implement `SelfNaming` interface, again I don't get `IllegalStateException`

Though not very sure, but I think implementing `SelfNaming` interface is not a very good idea as the javadocs of `SelfNaming` interface says that:

> This interface is mainly intended for internal usage.

I'm not sure if it is the problem with using `SelfNaming` interface or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Can you please explain this behavior and point me to the fundamentals that I'm missing.

PS: some of my findings: (might be unrelated)
From [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html) I found this caution point:

> Do not use interface-based AOP proxies in combination with autodetection of JMX annotations in your bean classes.

I don't completely understand this, but is this the rule that I'm violating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possibly a bug; `injectNotificationPublisherIfNecessary` only takes any action if your class also implements `NotificationPublisherAware`.

This would be invalid since we don't have an `objectName`, yet, because the bean is lazy and this would violate the contract for `ModelMBeanNotificationPublisher`.

I don't know if `postProcessTargetObject` can ignore the assert if the resource doesn't implement the publisher aware interface, or whether the publisher injection needs to be made lazily too. I don't know the internals well enough.

I suggest you open an `SPR` [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) so the Spring Team can take a look and give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I've raised a Jira issue.

Comment: This is a bug. Fix will be available from 5.0.12 5.1.4 [SPR-17592](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17592)